# Error connecting to centos server through a particular client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, centos

When i try to ssh`(ssh -i xyz.pem blah@blah.in)` to my centos server instance through my ubuntu client, it gives this error:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 56: Bad configuration option: clientaliveinterval
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Interestingly, other systems are able to successfully login with the same pem file. Also,the `clientaliveinterval` configuration option also does not exist in the ssh_config file. Surely, nothing needs to be done on the server, then what should be done locally? Is caching happening here?

Why is this happening with my local ubuntu client only. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option in the client config `ssh_config`. You probably meant `ServerAliveInterval`.

Replace the option `clientaliveinterval` on row 56 of your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (on client) with  `ServerAliveInterval` and you should be ok.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with the config file, the mentioned configuration is not at all there. Just that, i may have given once but reverted. But, when i ssh from my client, it still shows this. As i told, others client are able to ssh. So, seems like a client issue, may be a specific IP is denied due to some reason.

Comment: Oh, well a configuration change was made locally in my ubuntu ssh_config file. which i have reverted now. Just dint click that client also can have config file. Issue is resolved now.

Comment: Exactly as I wrote. There is the button on the left, to choose the answer as a solution. Please, use that if you still didn't found it.